# Windows 7 Black Login Screen Dead End

Tags: windows-7, windows

Ok I've been on google 4 hours now and here is where I am:
Windows 7 machine worked perfectly last night, this morning it can't reach the login in screen normally or in safe mode. 
In normal: it reaches login screen stage fast, but then hangs at the dreaded black screen with a cursor and does not resolve (waited over an hour hoping).
In safe mode: it manages to to give me the blue background but not the login area.

Windows 7 was pre-installed (no discs) and attempts to access System Repair and even try to run a start-up repair are a dead end: I can F8, select "repair system", but I can not go beyond that  because it requires an admin password. I have used biometric (fingerprint) login for years and do not remember the admin password and there is no 2nd admin account -yeah I know better, but here I am -.

Is there a work around to run a restore points? I'm hoping my problem is that simple or at least that is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It could be file or file system corruption.

[Run chkdsk from the command prompt in Windows RE](http://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=6565) (boot from a [W7 System Repair disc](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/5409/create-a-system-repair-disc-in-windows-7/) or a regular W7 install disc) System repair disc can be made on any W7 PC, just be sure that PC is the same bit version as the one you are going to repair, 32 or 64bit.

If that does not get it booting properly try running [System File Checker offline](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-sfc-offline-windows-7-vista/) from Windows RE.

You can also run system restore [from the System Repair disc](http://www.mytechguide.org/8515/use-system-repair-disc-restore-windows-7-vista/) you make. I would try this last after following my other suggestions.